# How to retrieve grouped messages ordered by date SQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Let's pretend I have the following "messages" table

```
ID (auto)   Sender     Receiver    Msg        Date (datetime)
1           Dave       John        Hi         01/01/2013
2           John       Dave        Hello      02/01/2013
3           James      Dave        U there?   02/02/2013
4           Dave       James       Yup        02/03/2013
5           Dave       Simon       Hey        02/03/2013
```

I want the list of people Dave is talking to ordered by Date.

```
Simon
James
John
```

I'm getting stuck on how to Group them without including "Dave" in one query.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: oldest to newest or vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want the *distinct* list of people that Dave is talking to:

```
select (case when receiver = 'Dave' then Sender else Receiver end)
from messages m
where 'Dave' in (Receiver, Sender)
group by (case when receiver = 'Dave' then Sender else Receiver end)
order max(date) desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

This will give you everyone Dave has sent a message to and recieved a message from ordered by Date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Receiver) FROM messages WHERE Sender = 'Dave' ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: The OP never asked for a full row of data and this answer produces duplicates. -1

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Receiver FROM messages WHERE Sender = "Dave"
AND Receiver NOT IN (SELECT Sender FROM messages WHERE Receiver = "Dave")
UNION
SELECT Sender FROM messages WHERE Receiver = "Dave"
```

Comment: That was not me, just to clarify