# group by different user names other than the receiver name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following `"tblA"` and `"tblB"` table:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  sender varchar(255),
  receiver varchar(255),
  msg varchar(255),
  date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  sno varchar(255),
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver, msg,date) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:19:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09'),
('3', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:24:09'),
('3', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:25:19'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '3', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '3', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09'),
('1', '4', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('1', '5', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '6', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '7', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('8', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09');


INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');
```

I want the list of people `Aa` is talking to ordered by Date  (Last entry for each user group).

```
Bb
Cc
Dd
Ee
Ff
Gg
Hh
```

I'm getting stuck on how to Group them without including `"Aa"` in one query.

Comment: where is your query code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select b.name
from tblA a join
     tblB b
     on b.id in (a.receiver, a.sender)
where b.name <> 'Aa'
order by date desc;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f8c/2) is a SQL Fiddle.  Note that your above code has a few semicolons that should be commas.

EDIT:

If you want the most recent date, then use:

```
select b.name
from tblA a join
     tblB b
     on b.id in (a.receiver, a.sender)
where b.name <> 'Aa'
group by b.name
order by max(date) desc;
```

EDIT II:

To filter by rows that just have `'Aa'`:

```
select b.name
from tblA a join
     tblB b
     on b.id in (a.receiver, a.sender)
where b.name <> 'Aa' and
      exists (select 1
              from tblB b2
              where b2.name = 'Aa' and
                    b2.id in (a.receiver, a.sender)
             )
group by b.name
order by max(date) desc;
```

Comment: Sir is it possible to get query something like you have stated here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683525/how-to-retreive-grouped-messages-ordered-by-date-sql      `select (case when receiver = 'Dave' then Sender else Receiver end)
from messages m
where 'Dave' in (Receiver, Sender)
group by (case when receiver = 'Dave' then Sender else Receiver end)
order max(date) desc;`

Comment: @jason . . . The situations are different, because the name was stored directly in the message table that time.  In this case, the name is in a separate table, which results in what I think is a more elegant query.

Comment: Also Sir   http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f8c/9   here there are other users other than `Aa` or `1` .How do I eliminate the others.

Comment: I posted a new question Sir Please look into .I combined both the tables as of now But the previous query not working properly for integrated table.Thanks again.